# Mongoose: Updating many entries starves connection pool

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

So I receive on my node server 80,000+ records at a time that need to be put into Mongo as updates.  I am aware that mongoose doesn't support this functionality, so each one has be be updated individually.

When I do this however, even when a connection pool is set up to be say 100, it still overwhelms the connection pool and the result is that any other web or system traffic needing to do a database call cannot complete.  Is there any way to have a model limit the amount of connection it uses, or any other good way to work around this?  For now we are resource limited to having only a single db or node instance to handle front and back end items.

Any comments or suggestions to try welcome.

Thanks

Comment: it'd be great if you could post some relevant code.  As a general answer I'd suggest batching  your requests.

Answer (score 0):

You *can* perform bulk updates with Mongoose, using [`Model.bulkWrite()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.bulkWrite).

The documentation doesn't specify how many documents you can update per batch, but [the MongoDB documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/reference/method/db.collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp/#execution-of-operations) documenting the underlying mechanism seems to suggest that you *might* be able to send all 80K updates at once.

Comment: Thanks Robert,  Will give it a try